# What exactly is the patent on?

Tags: claims, specification

In reference to the patent: [USD433631](https://www.google.com/patents/USD433631)

Is the patent on the idea of a label that rips in the middle of the jar? Is there any way to find out more information about this patent?

Answer (score 1):

Design Patent Claims:-

ornamental design for a peanut butter jar.

in my opinion It has something to do with opening of Jar with tear strip seal if it has been opened label will rip off.

I tried to search inventor in Google but nothing extra ordinary came up.

Comment: Careful ... design patents should (practically) never have to do with functionality ... ONLY the 'look / appearance' of what is depicted and claimed.

Answer (score 1):

This is a design patent, so it's a patent that protects the appearance of this "peanut butter jar" with a tear-off strip in the middle.  It doesn't protect a label that rips in the middle of the jar, because that's not what is illustrated.  And what is protected is exactly what is shown in the figures.